# Finisar.SQLite.SQLiteException when printing data to sqlite database

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, exception

I'm making a game envolving users and I'm getting a  Finisar.SQLite.SQLiteException when running. This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Finisar.SQLite;

namespace Racing_Manager
{
public partial class SaveNameBox : Form
{
    public string command;

    public string savedName;
    public string firstName;
    public string savedTeamName;
    public string surname;

    public SQLiteConnection sql_con;
    public SQLiteCommand sql_cmd;
    public SQLiteDataReader DB;

    public void setConnection()
    {
        sql_con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=database.sqlite;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;");
    }
    public static SaveNameBox create = new SaveNameBox();
    public SaveNameBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //Save Name
    private void TextBoxSaveName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        savedName = TextBoxSaveName.Text;
    }

    //Team Name
    private void teamName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        savedTeamName = teamName.Text;
    }

    //First Name
    private void textBoxFirstName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        firstName = textBoxFirstName.Text;
    }

    //Surname
    private void textBoxSurname_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        surname = textBoxSurname.Text;
    }

    //Confirmation
    private void confirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        command = String.Format("INSERT INTO Users VALUES ({0},{1},{2},{3})", savedName, firstName, surname, savedTeamName);
        ExecuteQuery(command);
    }


    public void ExecuteQuery(string command)
    {
        setConnection();
        sql_con.Open();
        sql_cmd.CommandText = command;
    }

}
}
```

The exception is on this line:
    sql_con.Open();
How do I fix this? Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your connections string is correct. here is a great [website](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite/) :

Comment: The connection string is correct. But it says that the file isn't a database (although the extension is .db) or is encrypted. I have no clue how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the database extension.

`sql_con = new SQLiteConnection("DataSource=database.db;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;");`